# How can I make the script level styles imitate TeX?

Tags: formatting, stylesheet

In math mode in $\TeX$, there are four styles that are used to determine what font will be used to typeset parts of a formula.  In decreasing hierarchical order, they are, with default font size in parentheses:

- $d$: \displaystyle (10 pt)
- $t$: \textstyle (10 pt)
- $s$: \scriptstyle (7 pt)
- $ss$: \scriptscriptstyle (5 pt)

In-line mathematics formulas start at \textstyle; displayed formulas start at \displaystyle.  Different fonts are defined for each style. The style in TeX are implemented by defining three fonts (for each font family, etc. -- unnecessary details omitted).  Both \displaystyle and \textstyle use the same font.

In fractions, the styles progress
$$ d(10\,pt) \rightarrow t(10\,pt) \rightarrow s(7\,pt) \rightarrow ss(5\,pt) \rightarrow ss(5\,pt) \rightarrow \cdots$$
In exponents, the styles progress
$$ \left.{d(10\,pt) \atop t(10\,pt)}\right\rbrace \rightarrow s(7\,pt) \rightarrow ss(5\,pt) \rightarrow ss(5\,pt) \rightarrow \cdots$$

Example:

$$d(10\,pt)^{7 pt^{5pt^{5pt^{5pt^{5pt}}}}} + {t(10\,pt)^{7pt^{5pt}} \over t(10\,pt)+{s(7pt)^{5pt^{5pt}}\over s(7pt)+{ss(5pt)^{5pt}\over ss(5pt)+{ss(5pt)^{5pt}\over ss(5pt)}}}}$$

Below is the default *Mathematica* behavior on a similar fraction.  Note that the size of the first level of the fraction is reduced.  The size of the exponents `5` on `d` continue to decrease until the last step.  And the spacing around the `+` in the fractions does not occur.

[image: Default]

If we set `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False`, we get no change in font size in the exponents or fractions and the spacing around the `+` remains.

[image: AllowScriptLevelChange->False]

Is there any way to imitate the behavior of $\TeX$? Or to get close?

Related: [Adjusting size and positioning of math notation in a Mathematica notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67724/adjusting-size-and-positioning-of-math-notation-in-a-mathematica-notebook) and [Any way to make my equations look better, more Latex like?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/any-way-to-make-my-equations-look-better-more-latex-like).  However, to mimic $\TeX$, we cannot simply suppress the change in size in fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* keeps track of a [`ScriptLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScriptLevel.html) to control the size of fractions and exponents.  Normally the script level increases by one in the numerator and denominator of a fraction, unless the option `AllowScriptLevelChange -> False` is set.  The script level also increases for each exponent. When the `ScriptLevel` increases, the font size is changed by the corresponding factor in [`ScriptSizeMultipliers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScriptSizeMultipliers.html).  A setting

```
ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {s1, s2, ..., sn}
```

indicates at the i-th change of level, the font size is to be multiplied by `si`. For changes after the n-th level change, the multiplier is `sn`.  There is also the option [`ScriptMinSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScriptMinSize.html) which puts a lower limit on how small the font size can get.

To mimic TeX font sizes in displayed formulas, we need to do two things. For the fractions, set `ScriptSizeMultipliers` to `{1., 0.7, 5./7., 1.}` in the `BaseStyle` of `FractionBoxOptions` of the formula's cell or cell style; and for the exponents set `ScriptSizeMultipliers` for the cell or cell's style to `{0.7, 5./7., 1.}`:

```
ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {0.7, 0.7142857, 1.},
FractionBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> {ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {1., 0.7, 0.7142857, 1.}}}
```

The final `1.` in `ScriptSizeMultipliers` means that further increases in `ScriptLevel` beyond level 4 will not affect the font size.  Because of that, we do not need to worry about specifying `ScriptMinSize`, provided it is small enough.

These options may be set in the Option Inspector: Formatting Options > Expression Formatting > ...

- SpecificBoxOptions > FractionBoxOptions > BaseStyle
- DisplayOptions > ScriptSizeMultipliers

One can use the Option Inspector to edit a single cell or a style in the stylesheet.

The option [`AutoSpacing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AutoSpacing.html) affects the spacing of formulas, but changing it (it can only be `True` or `False`) has no effect on fractions.  Apparently when the [`ScriptLevel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScriptLevel.html) is greater than `0`, autospacing is off.  The workaround is to manually space around operations like `+`.

Here is the result of the setting the `ScriptSizeMultipliers` in a `"Text"` cell:

[image]

Spaces or `\[ThinSpace]` etc. may be added if desired.  Perhaps someone will know an automatic way to have the spacing adjusted, at least at the first level where it is most obvious.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, for such detailed answer. It is certainly of a high value.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Just stumbled on this and I do need this. When I open the Options Inspector, there is a drop down box at the top left. Choices are Global Preferences, Selected Notebook, Selected, and because of what I have open, "Writing Assistant", and "section13_3_part2.nb". Which of these did you pick to make your settings for the future?

Comment: @David I used the "Selected".  One way: Select the cell, then use the Options Inspector.  Second way: Edit the stylesheet, create and/or select the cell for the style you wish to edit, and then use the Options Inspector.  I haven't tried it with notebook or global choice.  I would avoid making global changing. I might do something I'd have hard time undoing.

Comment: @MichaelE2. I think I used Selected Notebook as I wanted this to work in all equations I entered in display text mode. My whole notebook became more readable.